# Prestashop display all products form category without pagination

Tags: categories, prestashop

I am building a Module for the category page in prestashop.

Basically in my module.php I have this code:

```
$category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(),(int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
    $nb = (int)(Configuration::get('MOD_NBR'));
    $products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));

    $this->smarty->assign(array(
        'myproducts' => $products,
        'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
        'homeSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
    ));
```

Then in mymodule.tpl I have this:

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=myproducts}

+ other stuff
```

The problem is that I need to get all the products inside the category, but it is only displaying the products on the first page. I can't delete or modify pagination completely, because I need the other products on the category page to be paginated, but in my module I want to get all the products at once (after I will filter them to show only some of them).

As you may see I am kind of lost, but also so desperate, I will appreciate any guidance :)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have:

```
$products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));
```

which corresponds to:

```
/**
  * Return current category products
  *
  * @param integer $id_lang Language ID
  * @param integer $p Page number
  * @param integer $n Number of products per page
  * @param boolean $get_total return the number of results instead of the results themself
  * @param boolean $active return only active products
  * @param boolean $random active a random filter for returned products
  * @param int $random_number_products number of products to return if random is activated
  * @param boolean $check_access set to false to return all products (even if customer hasn't access)
  * @return mixed Products or number of products
  */
public function getProducts($id_lang, $p, $n, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, $get_total = false, $active = true, $random = false, $random_number_products = 1, $check_access = true, Context $context = null)
```

So you are asking for page `1` and `$nb` or `10` elements.
Try adding before that line `$nb = 10000;` to show up to 10k products (and feel free to increase it if your category has more than 10k products)

So it should be something like:

```
$category = new Category(Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory(),(int)Context::getContext()->language->id);
$nb = 10000;
$products = $category->getProducts((int)Context::getContext()->language->id, 1, ($nb ? $nb : 10));

$this->smarty->assign(array(
    'myproducts' => $products,
    'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
    'homeSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
));
```

**UPDATE**: Reviewing your question I've found that in your template you are iterating `$products` variable, but assigning it as `myproducts`. I'm guessing smarty has the assigned variables `$products` with only the first page and `$myproducts` with the ones you have obtained.

Try updating your template to:

```
{foreach from=$myproducts item=product name=myproducts}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try it, but it didn't work. I guess it is because I am inserting it in the category page, so it keeps that page configuration.. do you have any other idea? thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with something I've found re-reading your question, could you try if it works? If it works, could You try the updated part without the first suggested modification?